# VF with JQuery popup with lookup inputfield - selecting record has JS error - Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined

Tags: visualforce, jquery, lookup

VF with JQuery popup with lookup inputfield - selecting record has JS error - Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined

VF + [JQuery popup + account lookup/inputfield] -> click to select account -> lookup popup -> selecting account = **JS error** on the lookup popup: **Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined**

What am I missing?
[I have a few very similar VF pages that this works well ...]

Cheers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure why bu t moving some apex:form around and not append the JQuery dialog to anything seems to allowed this to work...

So slightly different than above:

```
<apex:form>
                            <apex:outputPanel styleClass="requiredInput" layout="block">
                                <apex:outputPanel styleClass="requiredBlock" layout="block"/>
                                <apex:inputField id="confirmnewcust" value="{!currentLead.Confirm_New_Customer__c}"/>
                            </apex:outputPanel>
                            <br/>
                            <apex:outputPanel styleClass="requiredInput" layout="block">
                                <apex:outputPanel styleClass="requiredBlock" layout="block"/>
                                <apex:inputField id="confirmnewcustacc" value="{!currentLead.Account__c}"/>                
                            </apex:outputPanel>
                            </apex:form>
```